# Openshift, is it posible for 2 apps in the same gear to communicate with each other?

Tags: openshift

I have 2 services in the same gear in Openshift, my question is it even possible for these services to call each other, or even to call an external service, with no security problem or restriction, cause I got some errors?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by communication?

You always can establish communication via several ways:

1. **read/write from file**
2. **read/write to socket**, usually your apps running into 127.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx address space.
   For example, write wo 127.8.252.129:8010 socket from one app and read from another as it was on local machine.
3. You can start outside communications via HTTP, ports for SIP closed for security reasons.

Comment: I simply want to deploy a web service and a web servie client of this WS, but I got some errors permission denied

Comment: @Soula could you elaborate? I'm running WS on my instance and standalone web-scraper which communicates with my server app periodically.

Comment: Well I have I have a web service that do some function, and the web serviec client calls this function (it's created using the WSDL file of the WS and calling the stub..) the 2 services are wrapped in war file each, and deployed in Tomcat app that I created in Openshift using jboss (NOT DIY). The problem is  that in the call I have axis fault, binding fault and permission denied